# How do I run a Python Script in a Java web application?

Tags: java, python, web, web-applications, com

I need to run a Python script (write input and read output) inside my Java application that will eventually be uploaded onto the web. How do I do this such that it is compatible with the web? I've tried things like `Jython` and `Runtime.exec()` in Java and I think both require `Python` to be installed on the computer (correct me if I'm wrong) but I want the app to be run by anyone on the web.

The Python script imports `win32com.client` to operate on a `COM` object. It reads in a .csv file, runs the external software, then writes a .csv file using the methods RCSV(...), Run(...) and WCSV(...). Instead of a .csv file, I would like this data to be accessed from my Java app directly. This is my python script in full for reference:

```
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import VARIANT
import csv

# This will import VT_VARIANT
import pythoncom

#dictionary function designed to read .csv file
def RCSV(address):
        input=[]
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(open(address, 'r'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        headers = csv_reader.fieldnames
        for line in csv_reader:
                for i in range(len(csv_reader.fieldnames)):
                        input.append(line[csv_reader.fieldnames[i]])
        InVal=[]
        for i in range(int(len(input)/len(headers))):
                InVal.append([])
        for i in range(len(InVal)):
                for j in range(i*len(headers), (i+1)*len(headers)):
                        InVal[i].append(input[j])
        return InVal

#dictionary function which writes a .csv file given its address
def WCSV(address, output, headers):
    with open(address, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=headers, lineterminator = '\n')
        writer.writeheader()

        for i in range(len(output[0])):
            writer.writerow({headers[x]: output[x][i] for x in range(len(headers))})

def Run(InType,InDesc,InVal,OutType,OutDesc):
    FieldArray = VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_VARIANT | pythoncom.VT_ARRAY, InDesc)
    AllValueArray=[None]*len(InVal)

    for i in range(len(InVal)):
        AllValueArray[i]=VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_VARIANT | pythoncom.VT_ARRAY, InVal[i])

    object.ChangeParametersMultipleElement(InType, FieldArray, AllValueArray)
    object.RunScriptCommand("SolvePowerFlow")
    OutVal = object.GetParametersMultipleElement(OutType, OutDesc,'')
    return OutVal

# This will establish the connection
object = win32com.client.Dispatch("pwrworld.SimulatorAuto") 
filename= r"C:\Users\janusz\Desktop\NTU microgrid topology\ICESO Scaledown microgrid.pwb"
object.OpenCase(filename)

# Reading inputs from a .csv
ADIN='IN.csv'
InVal = RCSV(ADIN)

InType = "GEN"
InDesc = ["BusNum", "GenID", "GenMW"]

OutType = "BUS"
OutDesc = ["BUSNUM", "BUSNAME", "BUSPUVOLT", "BUSANGLE", "BUSKVVOLT"]

OutVal = Run(InType,InDesc,InVal,OutType,OutDesc)
ADOUT='OUT.csv'
WCSV(ADOUT,OutVal[1],OutDesc)

#This will close the connection
del object
object = None
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the relationship of **all platforms** and **COM Object**?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misworded my question. What I meant was how do I implement Python script containing COM object in Java such that the Java app can be viewed on the web by any user?

Answer (score 2):

Jython works without Python being installed on the host, because it is a 100% Java implementation of Python. That being said, only `win32` clients can run win32 COM anything. So, that's never going to be compatible across any platform but win32 (and possibly win64 through wow).

Comment: Ok let's say I only want it to be viewable on Windows. How will I implement this COM object in Java? Jython doesn't let me do that because it doesn't include win32. I've tried Java-COM Bridge (JACOB) but I have no idea how to re-write my python script in java because their documentation is very brief. Here is a snippet of my python code where \n is a new line:
`object = win32com.client.Dispatch("pwrworld.SimulatorAuto") \n
filename = r"ICESO Scaledown microgrid.pwb" \n
object.OpenCase(filename)`

Comment: It might be significantly easier to deploy a python-based solution on windows on a private port, then you could query that server and pass the result back (making your Java application a middle-tier). Using COM in Java is not for the faint of heart.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by making Java the middle-tier. Does it mean that I run my web application on Python and embed the Java within the application?